# Why are only some materials ferromagnetic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, solid-state-physics

I've been told in my solid state class, that ferromagnetism occurs when electron spins are alligned. This happens, as I understand it, when it is "energitically favorable" and when the wavefunction is antisymmetric (with a symmetric spin part). What I don't understand is:

1) When the spin part is symmetric and the electrons are alligned, the Coloumb repulsion is minimized (due to the Pauli principle, the electrons move further apart) - should it not *always* be more energitically favorable for the spins to be alligned?

2) Why, for instance, is iron (Fe) ferromagnetic, while Manganese (Mn) is paramagnetic? I fail to see where the theory comes into play. By looking at their orbital structure, Mn has more unpaired valence electrons than Fe.

Comment: MinutePhysics has a video on this with pretty drawings.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM